# I want to take backup automatically of a SharePoint online list as excel file every day

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, backup, large-lists

I have a SharePoint online list with more than 9000 items and the list is being populated on daily basis. I am taking backup manually every morning by saving the list as excel file in the document Library and in my local Computer.
My question is:
How can i automate that function?
May be a workflow that save the list as excel file every day in the document library?

Answer (score 1):

What do you plan to do with the backups? The format needed in the download will help determine the best solution.

If you are writing a little console application or PowerShell script to run as a Windows scheduled job you could use JSON and bring down the data in XML or REST format. This will also let you choose which columns to bring down, and can support a filter so you can bring down subsets, such as just the last day or the last week.

Something like:

```
http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('yourList')/items?$select=Id,Color,Title,Category


http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('yourList')/items?$select=Id,Color,Title,Category&$filter=Created gt '2016/01/01'&$top=10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Timer Job. Just choose the best moment to exec your code and that's all.

Maybe this page will help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [powershell script](http://sharepointdominic.blogspot.in/2012/10/export-list-data-using-powershell.html) to export list data to csv file and [create a windows task](http://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/002_HowTo/004_SharePointActions/012_SchedulingPowerShell.htm) to run this daily.

Comment: This is a good option but  the script is not for SharePoint online. Can you please  help me writing the script for SharePoint online .